# Javascript - Optimized way to extract a subset of elements from an array, based on specific criteria

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given an array of labels, I want to extract those values that begin with   keywords specified in a different array.

**Input:**   Two arrays - `labels`, `keys`.

**Required output:**

All values from `labels` array that begin with any of the values from `keys` array

**What I already tried:**

```js
    const keys= ['activity', 'admin'];
    const labels = ["accountTypes.GROUP_ACCOUNT",
    "accountTypes.SINGLE_ACCOUNT",
    "activity.active",
    "activity.inactive",
    "admin.dictionaries.name",
    "admin.group.details.addedDate",
    "admin.group.details.enterDescription"];

    let arr = [];
    keys.forEach( key => {
      labels.forEach(label => {
        if (label.indexOf(key) === 0){
          arr.push(label);
        }
      });
    });

    console.log(arr)
```

**Help required:**

I want to refactor this code without `indexOf()` and remove useless groupArr. I want to use ^ES6 or/and lodash

Comment: What exactly you want to return ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `filter` along with the function `includes` to filter the desired elements/strings.

```js
const keys = ['activity', 'admin'];
const labels = ["accountTypes.GROUP_ACCOUNT","accountTypes.SINGLE_ACCOUNT","activity.active","activity.inactive","admin.dictionaries.name","admin.group.details.addedDate","admin.group.details.enterDescription"];

let arr = labels.filter(l => {
  let [label] = l.split(".");
  return keys.includes(label);
});
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: labels.filter(l => keys.includes(l.substring(0,l.indexOf('.'))))

Answer (score 0):

Subset of an array can be extracted by using **filter** method.

The **filter** method takes a function that returns boolean value as the input.
The boolean function can contain the logic for comparison.

**Here is the working solution to extract values of 'labels' array that begin with text from 'keys' array:**

```
// File name: array-subset.js

const keys= ['activity', 'admin']

const labels = ["accountTypes.GROUP_ACCOUNT",
    "accountTypes.SINGLE_ACCOUNT",
    "activity.active",
    "activity.inactive",
    "admin.dictionaries.name",
    "admin.group.details.addedDate",
    "admin.group.details.enterDescription"]


// Function to be used as the input for 'filter' method

function matchedValue(label) {
        return keys.includes(label.split(".")[0])
}


console.log(labels.filter(matchedValue))
```

**Output:**

```
$ node array-subset.js 
[ 'activity.active',
  'activity.inactive',
  'admin.dictionaries.name',
  'admin.group.details.addedDate',
  'admin.group.details.enterDescription' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use difference, differenceWith, and includes of lodash

```
const keys= ['activity', 'admin'];
    const labels = ["accountTypes.GROUP_ACCOUNT",
    "accountTypes.SINGLE_ACCOUNT",
    "activity.active",
    "activity.inactive",
    "admin.dictionaries.name",
    "admin.group.details.addedDate",
    "admin.group.details.enterDescription"];

   _.difference(labels,_.differenceWith(labels, keys,(label,key) => _.includes(label,key)));
```